# Create object from JSON using headers from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a JSON object that is similar to below:

```
vehicles:
{
    trucks: [
        "Ford",
        "Toyota",
        "Dodge",
    ],
    suvs: [
        "Honda",
        "GMC",
    ],
    cars: [
        "Pontiac",
        "Lotus",
        "Aston-Martin",
        "Porsche",
        "Subaru"
     ]
}
```

I would like to loop through this and create my own object, however I cannot find out how to do it without using three different loops for each type of vehicle.

Here is my attempt below:

```
let vehicleObject = {
    vehicles: []
}

// I'm getting the response back from a http request
Object.keys(body.vehicles).forEach(function (k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.vehicles.k.length; i++) {
        vehicleObject.vehicles.push({
            vehicle_type: k,
            manufacturer: body.vehicles.k[i]
        });
    }
});
```

However, this just leads me to "cannot read property length of undefined. I know I can accomplish this with a switch or three if's but I would like to learn a more efficient way, if possible. Thank you.

Comment: I think the loop should be `for (let i = 0; i < body.vehicles[k].length; i++)`, similarly the manufacturer field should be `body.vehicles[k][i]`

Comment: how looks the output object that you wanna get? (write it using json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop should be like this:

```
Object.keys(body.vehicles).forEach(function (k) {
    for (let i = 0; i < body.vehicles[k].length; i++) {
        vehicleObject.vehicles.push({
            vehicle_type: k,
            manufacturer: body.vehicles[k][i]
        });
        console.log(vehicles[k].length)
    }
});
```

When you iterate over each key you are getting name of the keys in k and then to get the array from body.vehicles object you need to do something like body.vehicles[k].

Comment: Works perfectly and I understand my mistake now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To declare global variable for the scope you should probably use `var` instead of `let`

```
var vehicleObject = {
    vehicles: []
};
```

`let` is reachable only inside `{...}` block, like you used it in your `for {...}` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want an array of objects, like:

```
[{ vehicle_type: 'suvs', manufacturer: 'Honda' }, ... ]
```

Assuming, `body` contains the vehicles object:

```
const { vehicles } = body
const vehicleTypes = Object.keys(vehicles)
const getManufacturers = type => vehicles[type]
const createVehicle = (type, mf) => ({ vehicle_type: type, manufacturer: mf })

let flattenedVehicles = []
vehicleTypes.forEach(type => {
  flattenedVehicles.push(
    getManufacturers(type).map(mf => createVehicle(type, mf))
  )
})

// flattenedVehicles now has desired array
```